# Paypal Checkin Tab expires

Tags: magento, paypal

I am using the Magento Paypal Orderahead extention.

Everything works fine through the Paypal App picking up the store via the Paypal Here concept.

I can push through a successful Checkin transaction, but when I try the second transaction, I get the following error in the Log files:

```
[errorCode] => 600010
[errorType] => tab/not_found
[message] => The specified tab could not be found, or has expired
[developerMessage] => The specified tab could not be found. This could be because the tab has been cancelled or expired.
[correlationId] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any ideas why this Tab expires, or what expires it?

The Tab should be alive for as long as the Paypal App is alive with your Paypal session.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out from Paypal, that after one transaction, you are supposed to leave the location and come back later.

Therefore the reason why the Tab expires after 1 successful sale, and nothing we can do about it, until Paypal changes how their API operates in this scenario.

The other fun bit too, is that there is no refunds afterwards via the Paypal Checkin solution..... You have to manually do a refund to the customer, if for in case the sale went through online, and then you realized another customer just took the last stock from the shelf at the physical store...

Hope this help someone from not pulling their hair out, when working with the Paypal POS module in Magento.